# How do I scale an item in a scroll area without changing the size of the scroll area

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have several square items inside a scrollable area. Each item increases in scale by 10% when rolled over. When the group of items is either significantly taller or shorter than the scroll area, everything works fine.

The problem occurs when the height of the items is only slightly shorter than the height of the scrollable area. This only occurs in Chrome. What I think is happening is that when an item increases in size by 10%, the entire div containing the items also increases to larger than the height of the scroll area, at which point the scrollbar flashes on and off.

[Gif of scrollbar flashing on and off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXyvH.gif)

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening?

Here's a CodePen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VPzoPK?editors=1100#0

And the associated code:

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.scrollable {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 495px;
}

.grid__col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.square_image {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.square_image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit: Mentioned that this is a chrome issue

Comment: That isn't happening to me when I hover over any of the boxes.

Comment: I could not recreate the issue in Safari, Chrome, Firefox or Opera on Mac. I cannot use Edge.

Comment: You can force the scrollbar to be always visible `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm seeing this in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable scrolling:

```
div {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

To force scrolling:

```
div {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Fixed css:

```
body {
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .scrollable {
        overflow-y: auto;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 495px;
      }

      .grid__col {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25%;
        margin: 10px;
        background-color: blue;
      }

      .square_image {
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }

      .square_image:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }
```

For this to work, add additional 2 boxes to your div ;)

```
<div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I would prefer to only show the scrollbar if the content is longer than the scrollable area.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dumb, but I don't see any difference between your and my CSS.

Comment: There is no difference :P You have 3 solutions. 1. disable the scrollbar totally. 2. add 1 or more boxes to enable the scroll permanently. 3. add a little width to the scrollable div, like width: 330px;

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two differents approaches to take:

### 1- Hide your scroll using `overflow-y: hidden`

```css
body {
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .scrollable {
        width: 300px;
        background-color: white;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        max-height: 495px;
      }

      .grid__col {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25%;
        margin: 10px;
        background-color: blue;
      }

      .square_image {
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }

      .square_image:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

### 2- Force the scroll to appear always using `overflow: scroll`

```css
body {
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .scrollable {
        width: 300px;
        background-color: white;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        max-height: 495px;
      }

      .grid__col {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 25%;
        margin: 10px;
        background-color: blue;
      }

      .square_image {
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        border: 2px solid black;
      }

      .square_image:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid__col">
          <div class="square_image"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But you should keep a relation between the effect and the size, still when you are not seeing the undesired effect it is still happening.

There is a problem related to the design and the way it looks like in this case.
I Hope to help you.

Comment: Ideally I'd keep `overflow-y: auto` so that it'll be hidden when the content is shorter than the scroll area and visible when it's larger.

Answer (score 0):

Either give the `.scrollable` div more width, to account for the scrollbar appearing:

```
.scrollable {
    width: 330px;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.scrollable {
  width: 330px; /* changed from '300px' */
  background-color: white;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 495px;
}
.grid__col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.square_image {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.square_image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or simply force the scrollbar to be always visible:

```
.scrollable {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.scrollable {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* changed from 'auto' */
  max-height: 495px;
}
.grid__col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.square_image {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.square_image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid__col">
      <div class="square_image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```